# Calculate high byte and low byte in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, byte

How to calculate the `highByte` and `lowByte` of any number;

Example :

```
let mValue = 26513
```

hex representation of `mValue` = `0x6791`

Then how find high and low byte of above number?

Answer (score 1):

> Updated for swift :

*below solution works for me:*

```
    let mVal = 26513 // hex value of mVal = 0x6791 (UInt16)
    let highByte = (mVal >> 8) & 0xff  // hex value of highByte = 0x0067 (UInt8)
    let lowByte = mVal & 0xff // hex value of lowByte = 0x0091 (UInt8)

    print("highByte: \(highByte)\nLowByte: \(lowByte)")
```